# Unable to locate package matlab-psychtoolbox-3

Tags: package, ubuntu-14.04, psychtoolbox

I am trying to install the matlab-psychtoolbox-3 and I recieve this error:

> $ sudo apt-get install matlab-psychtoolbox-3
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package matlab-psychtoolbox-3

Can anybody tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is old, but for anyone struggling with this error while installing psych-toolbox this is how to solve it. Basically, the error is because the neurodebian package is not installed in your system. To do so, run: sudo apt-get install neurodebian

Once you do this, then follow the next step, i.e., sudo apt-get install matlab-psychtoolbox-3

Then you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you've added the [neurodebian](http://neuro.debian.net/) ppa to your system witch is the easyest way to get the psychtoolbox to ubuntu

try to update your packet list with `sudo apt-get update` and then try to install again with `sudo apt-get install matlab-psychtoolbox-3`

if that doesn’t help check your software sources and see if the neurodebian nonfree ppa is installed (all matlab stuff is part of the nonfree branch).
if you got the free branch installed remove it put add the non free branch:

```
wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/trusty.de-md.full | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 2649A5A9
```

that should do the trick