# Unable to install package matlab-psychtoolbox-3

Tags: psychtoolbox

I follow the step in the following [website](http://neuro.debian.net/install_pkg.html?p=matlab-psychtoolbox-3) to install psychtoolbox, however it keep showing unable to locate the package...
I've already look this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078759/unable-to-locate-package-matlab-psychtoolbox-3) I assume that the neurodebian nonfree ppa is installed since
this situation occur after I update to Ubuntu 21.04, which work properly under 20.04. The code is shown in the end of this section. I'm willing to provide any further info, please help.

the output is

```
josh777@josh777-Surface-Book-3:~$ wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/hirsute.au.full | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
--2021-07-13 00:24:48--  http://neuro.debian.net/lists/hirsute.au.full
Resolving neuro.debian.net (neuro.debian.net)... 129.170.233.11
Connecting to neuro.debian.net (neuro.debian.net)|129.170.233.11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 316 [audio/basic]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                                 100%[=============================================================>]     316  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

deb http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/neurodebian data main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/neurodebian data main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/neurodebian hirsute main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/neurodebian hirsute main contrib non-free
2021-07-13 00:24:48 (73.3 MB/s) - written to stdout [316/316]

josh777@josh777-Surface-Book-3:~$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.HFxaCmjF60/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xA5D32F012649A5A9
gpg: key A5D32F012649A5A9: "NeuroDebian Archive Key <pkg-exppsy-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
josh777@josh777-Surface-Book-3:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://mirror01.idc.hinet.net/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirror01.idc.hinet.net/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease                                                                   
Hit:3 http://mirror01.idc.hinet.net/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease                                                                 
Hit:4 http://mirror01.idc.hinet.net/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease                                                                  
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                           
Get:6 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                             
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                            
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                       
Hit:9 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release InRelease                 
Hit:10 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/neurodebian data InRelease
Hit:11 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/neurodebian hirsute InRelease
Get:12 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/neurodebian data/non-free amd64 Packages [5961 B]
Get:13 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/neurodebian data/non-free i386 Packages [5961 B]
Fetched 239 kB in 2s (97.2 kB/s)                            
Reading package lists... Done
josh777@josh777-Surface-Book-3:~$ sudo apt-get install matlab-psychtoolbox-3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package matlab-psychtoolbox-3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be some error in the repo / the repo index files? But we can download the two main Ubuntu 21.04 packages to a new empty folder from http://neurodebian.ovgu.de/debian/pool/non-free/p/psychtoolbox-3-nonfree/ ( `matlab-psychtoolbox-3` depends on `matlab-psychtoolbox-3-nonfree` )

wget [http://neurodebian.ovgu.de/debian/pool/non-free/p/psychtoolbox-3-nonfree/matlab-psychtoolbox-3_3.0.17.6-1~nd110+1_all.deb](http://neurodebian.ovgu.de/debian/pool/non-free/p/psychtoolbox-3-nonfree/matlab-psychtoolbox-3_3.0.17.6-1%7End110+1_all.deb)

wget [http://neurodebian.ovgu.de/debian/pool/non-free/p/psychtoolbox-3-nonfree/matlab-psychtoolbox-3-nonfree_3.0.17.6-1~nd110+1_amd64.deb](http://neurodebian.ovgu.de/debian/pool/non-free/p/psychtoolbox-3-nonfree/matlab-psychtoolbox-3-nonfree_3.0.17.6-1%7End110+1_amd64.deb)

And install with apt, to get the dependencies installed:

```
cd new-folder/
sudo apt install ./*
```

.... and you will be asked for MATLAB location.

Note: The file control from `matlab-psychtoolbox-3-nonfree` says

```
Depends: neurodebian-popularity-contest, psychtoolbox-3-lib (>= 3.0.17.6-1~nd110+1.dfsg), psychtoolbox-3-common (>= 3.0.17.6-1~nd110+1.dfsg), libx11-6, libxext6, libxfixes3, libxi6, freeglut3, libgl1-mesa-glx, libxmu6, libxpm4
```

... so maybe you also have to download `neurodebian-popularity-contest, psychtoolbox-3-lib, psychtoolbox-3-common` .